# Google Maps doesn't fadeIn when i click on the button

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, button, fadein

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#button {
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -25px;
margin-left: -75px;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
background-color: #4081FB;
font-size: 18px;
border: solid 1px #4081FB;
}
#button:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
#map {
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#button").click(function () {
$("#map").fadeIn("slow");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Open Map" />
<div id="map">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d26496.05743213355!2d151.12773775!3d-33.88946895!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1439976442653" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why when i click on the "Open Map" button, Google Maps doesn't not fade in. I have embedded Google Maps into the script and used jQuery fadeIn, however the map does not fadeIn when i click on the button. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry, `visibility hidden` There comes the problem. change it to `display:none`.

Comment: Thanks, however do you know why the map doesn't cover up the whole page even though i have background-size: cover; ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using visibility property for hiding that element, it will not work with `.fadeIn()`. Better you could use `display:none` to make it hidden. Or you could set opacity 0 to that element and then use `.animate('opacity',1)` to achieve what you want.